# SwiftUI ObservableObject with published array of Structs does not notify view of change

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject

**High Level Problem**
I have a view model which is hooked into Firebase which updates a published array of structs. For whatever reason it does not notify views depending on this Published variable of its change.

**Code**

***View Model***

```
@MainActor class RestaurantsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var restaurants: [Restaurant]
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    init() {
        self.restaurants = []
    
        db.collection("Restaurants").addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { [self] (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
        
            let newRestaurants = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Restaurant in
                    /* do stuff */
                }

            self.restaurants = newRestaurants
        }
    }
}
```

***Restaurant***

```
struct Restaurant: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let location: CLLocation
    let votes: Int

    init(id: String, name: String, location: CLLocation, votes: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.votes = votes
    }
}
```

***View (which I expect to be updating)***

```
struct RestaurantsView: View {
    // This is the same instance of the view model as the one recieving the database refreshes.
    // I've checked by printing the memory addresses of the view model in both places.
    @EnvironmentObject var restarauntViewModel: RestaurantsViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(content: {
            Text("")
            
            VStack(content: {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(content: {
                        ForEach(restarauntViewModel.restaurants, id: \.id) { restaurant in
                            RestaurantView(restaurant: restaurant)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

```
struct RestaurantView: View {
    @State var restaurant: Restaurant
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(content: {
            NameView(name: restaurant.name)
            VoteView(voteCount: restaurant.votes)
        })
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                /* do stuff */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**
Am I overlooking an obvious reason why the `ForEach` in my `RestaurantsView` is not updating when I receive a an update from my database?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In your view hierarchy, did you declare `@StateObject var restarauntViewModel = RestaurantsViewModel()` and use
 `.environmentObject(restarauntViewModel)` to pass it to the `RestaurantsView`?

Comment: Since you already have a modern RestaurantView struct to hold the view data you can remove the legacy RestaurantsViewModel object. Fetch from database in a `.task(id:)` modifier and store the result in a `@State`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@State` is a source of truth and should always be marked `private`, something like

```
 @State private var restaurant: Restaurant = .init()
```

What you need is a `@Binding`

```
 @Binding var restaurant: Restaurant
```

Which is a two way connection.

You implementation now makes a copy of the object and it looses connection to the parent.

The `@State` prevents any redrawing because SwiftUI uses it to maintain the view’s identity.

Your `ForEach` needs some minor changes.

```
ForEach($restarauntViewModel.restaurants, id: \.id) { $restaurant in

    RestaurantView(restaurant: $restaurant)
```

Comment: This wound up fixing it! I had some views inside of RestaurantView that also took @State variables that I had to fix. They were native types that I wound up just replacing with let constants instead. Thanks for the help!